# SQLAlchemy omits query results

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sqlalchemy

A left join query executed in SQLAlchemy omits certain fields which are returned when the query is executed directly on the database engine. My goal is to return a list of all *patients* and indicate if there is at least one *rating* by a set user.

I have two tables:

### **table 'patients'**

| id | patient_id | internal_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| prim.key |  |  |
| int | int | int |

### **table 'ratings'**

| id | user_id | patient_id | rating_a | rating_b | created | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| prim.key |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| int | int | int | int | int | datetime | varchar |

I'm using Python 3.9 on Windows (64Bit) and SQLAlchemy 2.0.13.

To perform a left join, I use the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy as db

def get_db_connection():
    engine = db.create_engine(dbstring)
    connection = engine.connect()
    return connection

conn = get_db_connection()

user_id = 1
sqlstatement = "SELECT * from patients LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, patient_id, created FROM ratings GROUP BY patient_id) ratings ON patients.patient_id = ratings.patient_id AND ratings.user_id = :user_id"

list = conn.execute(text(sqlstatement), {"user_id": user_id}).fetchall()

print(list)
```

When I execute the above statement directly on my database engine, this result is returned:

### result

| id | patient_id | internal_id | user_id | patient_id | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 00000001 | 1 | 1 | 2023-05-19 01:01:01 |
| 2 | 2 | 00000002 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |

Note that for id=2 there is no corresponding row in the **rating** table thus the joined columns *user_id, patient_id* and *created* remain (NULL).

The statement works as intended, but the Row object from SQLAlchemy looks like this:

| id | patient_id | internal_id | user_id | patient_id | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 00000001 | 1 | 1 | 2023-05-19 01:01:01 |
| 2 | None | 00000002 | None | None | None |

It omits the patient_id for the row where the left join results in joining (NULL) columns (See id=2; column patient_id).

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it due to duplicated column names? How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the duplicated column name.  So, don't pull the `patient_id` from the `ratings` column.  You know its going to be the same, right?  Just select `created`.

Comment: You have no aggregation function in the subquery that uses `GROUP BY`. So it's picking an arbitrary `user_id` and `created` value from each `patient_id` group. This doesn't make much sense.